# Drawing text with CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint - how to get font dimensions?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-graphics

Hoping this is fairly simple. Basically, I'm drawing some text onto an NSView and need to know the "physical" height and width of the glyphs being drawn.

The font is fixed-width so I don't need to worry about kerning, all I need to do is ensure each glyph is centred horizontally and vertically within its "space"

This isn't the actual code but I've re-written it in a way that should make it easier to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

```
CGFontRef myFontRef = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(myFontDataProvider);
CGContextSetFont(thisContext, myFontRef);
CGFloat fontSize = 1.0; //will be changeable later
CGContextSetFontSize(thisContext, fontSize);
CGRect charBounds = CGRectMake(x, y, widthPerChar, heightPerChar);
//paint charBounds with background colour
CGFloat textX = x + 2;
CGFloat textY = y + 5;
CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint(thisContext, textX, textY, (CGGlyph *)displayedString, 1);
```

If I was able to calculate the width of the displayed glyph it would be easy to work out what textX and textY should be.

Thanks in advance to anybody willing to assist.

Comment: This isn't really Cocoa or Objective-C (yet) despite the presence of NSView. Added generic `osx` tag.

Comment: Are you intently set on using pure Core Graphics to do the drawing of the glyphs (perhaps for performance or use of a pure `CGContext` or something)? Otherwise, you can do text measurement using some higher-level APIs like `NSText` (`NSString` and `NSAttributedString`) or `CoreText`. Might also be possible in Core Graphics, though I don't know offhand. IIRC, it's text-handling is fairly simple.

Comment: @NSGod: Performance is pretty important, yet I might look into CoreText again if I can make it fit a fixed size. Did work out how to calculate its width: by setting the drawing mode to kCGTextInvisible and using CGContextGetTextPosition to work out where the next character would be drawn - just need to work out the height now. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I don't see what you're doing with textOffsetX and Y? did you mean .x and y? If that's the case, I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partly worked it out from [this code](http://blog.mro.name/2010/08/uilabel-with-a-custom-cgfont/) - here's what I came up with:

```
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(thisContext, kCGTextInvisible);            
CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint(thisContext, 1, 1, (const CGGlyph *)"x", 1);
CGPoint postPosition = CGContextGetTextPosition(thisContext);
CGFloat textOffsetX = ((postPosition.x - 1) / 2);
CGFloat textOffsetY = (fontSize * 5);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(thisContext, kCGTextFillStroke);
```

Not a huge fan of doing it like this but it's working for now. At least it can be calculated once for each window resize which isn't too bad.

Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the width of single glyph in this way:

```
CGRect units;
 CGFontGetGlyphBBoxes(font, &glyph, 1, &units);
 float width = units.size.width/CGFontGetUnitsPerEm(font)*fontSize;
```